# How to return a value by passing it through a random set of functions?

Tags: java, recursion, random

I need help in figuring out how to generate a random set of functions.

Such as: `Sin(Cos(Average(x, y)))`

OR : `Cos(Tan(Sin(Sin(x)))`

etc..

The code I've come up with thus far is as follows, but I'm pretty certain it's not correct:

```
public class Functions {
public static double randomFunctions(int maxDepth, double x, double y) {
    int random ;
    double value = 1.0 ;
    if (maxDepth == 0) {
        random = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        if (random == 1 || random == 2) {

            return x ;
        }
        if (random == 3 || random == 4) {
            return y ;
        }
        if (random == 5) {
            return Math.random() * 2 - 1 ;
        }
    } else if (maxDepth != 0) {
        random = (int) (Math.random() * 17 + 1) ;
        if (random == 1 || random == 2 || random == 3) {
            return Math.sin(Math.PI * randomFunctions(maxDepth-1, x, y)) ;
        }
        if (random == 4 || random == 5 || random == 6) {
            return Math.cos(Math.PI * randomFunctions(maxDepth-1, x, y)) ;
        }
        if (random == 7 || random == 8 || random == 9) {
            return (randomFunctions(maxDepth-1, x, y) + randomFunctions(maxDepth-1, x, y))/2.0 ;
        }
        if (random == 10 || random == 11 || random == 12) {
            return (randomFunctions(maxDepth-1, x, y) + randomFunctions(maxDepth-1, x, y))/2.0 ;
        }
        if (random == 13 || random == 14) {
            System.out.println(random);
            return x  ;

        }
        if (random == 15 || random == 16) {
            return y ;
        }
        else {
            return (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Fail");
    return 0.0 ;



}
```

Any help or advice you can give me would be greatly appreciated. I know `Math.sin` & `cos` etc accept Radian values, but I'm thinking there is something wrong structurally.

Comment: Are you using Java 8 and comfortable with learning/using lambdas?

Comment: why not use switch case? even you are not using java 8, you can define an interface and make the code act exactly the same as you want.

Comment: I'll have a look at lambdas now, I'm very new to programming. I'm using Java 7

Comment: Yeah a switch case would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an array of functions, and then randomly choose functions from the array to call. To get you started, here is how you might declare your array:

```
// define a functional interface which we will use
public Interface MathFunction {
    public double apply(double d);
}   

// declare our array of functions, using three lambda functions to statically declare
// the array
MathFunction[] functions = {x -> {return Math.cos(x);}, 
                            x -> {return Math.sin(x);},
                            x -> {return Math.tan(x);}};
```

This will only work in Java 8. To do the same in Java 7, simply declare anonymous MathFunction classes like so:

```
class Cosine implements MathFunction {
    @Override
    public double apply(double d) {
        return Math.cos(d);
    }
}
```

Then, use these classes to create your array:

```
MathFunction[] functions = {new Cosine(), new Sine(), new Tangent()};
```

Putting it all together:

```
public static double randomFunctions(int maxDepth, double x, double y) {
    MathFunction[] functions = {new Cosine(), new Sine(), new Tangent()}; 

    int currX = x;
    int currY = y;

    // repeatedly apply functions to each value randomly
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDepth; i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        currX = r.nextInt(functions.length - 1);
        currY = r.nextInt(functions.length - 1);
    }

    // randomly return one of the two numbers
    Random r = newRandom();
    if (r.nextBoolean()) {
        return currX;
    } else {
        return currY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried to do before instead with "extends". Never thought about the function array though. I'm just a bit lost on how to enter in my two double values x & y. I know I have to use apply(double x, double y), but how do I apply that to all the functions?

Comment: And when returning a value for Math.cos(g) for instance, g would be the value return from deeper functions. How would I incorporate that into my apply method?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover this question. This could pretty easily be expanded to include functions which take in two numbers rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Java 7

You can have an interface:

```
interface Function {
    double apply(double x, double y);
}
```

And now:

```
final Function avg = new Function() {
    @Override
    public double apply(double x, double y) {
        return (x + y)/2;
    }
};

final Function sin = new Function() {
    @Override
    public double apply(double x, double y) {
        return Math.sin(x);
    }
};

final Function cos = new Function() {
    @Override
    public double apply(double x, double y) {
        return Math.cos(x);
    }
};

...
```

You can add `sin`, `cos`, `avg` etc. to a list, shuffle it, and apply the first `maxDepth` functions.

Comment: I think I see. Would this list be a list of functions, as in Functions[] list?

Comment: @Teakon It would be a `List<Function>`.

Comment: @Teakon that's an array and yes, you can have such array.

Comment: I'm not familiar with lists yet, so I'll have a look, but will it work if i create an array of Functions, shuffle the functions and then with a loop, execute each function by multiplying it onto a total value and then returning the total value?

Comment: Nevermind, doing that won't work for Sin and Cos like functions, but I think I have what I need now to figure it out. Thank you!